# How to extract a node from XmlDocument ignoring default namespace

Tags: c#, xml-namespaces, xmldocument

I need to extract a node's xml from XmlDocument the way it is, with no namespace attribute if it wasn't present initially.
Here is the XML file:

```
<app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" ...>
  <item/>
</app>
```

This is what I do in order to get a node:

```
var document = new new XmlDocument();
document.PreserveWhitespace = true;
document.LoadXml(sourceRootText);
...
var node = GetNode(document);
var text = node.OuterXml;
```

It returns the following result:

```
text = "<item xmlns='http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee' />";
```

Is there any way to tell document to not include namespace in node?
I understand why it is added, but I'd like to keep it without namespace.

Also, I can't use XDocument unfortunately because a lot of code already uses XmlDocument and its not easy for me to rework it now.

Edit: Actually I can try XDocument to parse XmlNode.OuterXml and then remove namespace, I will try this now.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same situation. Following is the solution I had applied where in I had stripped the xml from all the namespaces. may be this will help you out

```
XElement xdoc = stripNS(XElement.Parse(node.NextSibling.OuterXml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace));
                       XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                       using (XmlReader xmlReader = xdoc.CreateReader())
                       {
                           xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
                       }

static XElement stripNS(XElement root)
           {
               return new XElement(root.Name.LocalName, root.HasElements ? root.Elements().Select(el => stripNS(el)) : (object)root.Value);
           }
```

Comment: This will strip all attributes.